# Ionic $http giving null response

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, whitelist

I am also facing the same issue. Not able to solve the problem. I am using following versions of ionic and cordova.
Ionic : 1.7.14
cordova : 6.1.1

I have already installed whitelist plugin in my app and added the following lines in the config.xml.

Also try to remove android platform. but the issue remains same.

Please suggest. All suggestions are welcome.

Here is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>

        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="lib/angularLocalStorage/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
        
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.constants.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.services.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">

        </ion-nav-bar>

        <!--navigation view-->
        <ion-nav-view>
        </ion-nav-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
function  createHttpRequestObject = function (url, data, method, headers) {
            var req = {};
            req['method'] = method || 'POST';
            if (action) {
                req['url'] = url;
            }
            if (data) {                
                req['data'] = data;
            }
            req['headers'] = headers || { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };
            return req;
        }


var deferred = $q.defer();
$http(createHttpRequestObject('my-url.com/postData', data)) .success(function (res) {
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) { 
 alert(data)
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use $http ?

Comment: Can you also post your index.html and the value you are using for the Content Security Policy meta tag?

Comment: @SimonPrickett, i have added the index.html code in the question

Comment: @gregoireMotot Updated the question with http code

Comment: first of all check the end-point you are connecting to. The end-point might return null if the json encoding done there is not correct.also depends what data you posting and its quite possible that end-point returns null while processing that data set. Try checking the end-point in some rest client like postman

Comment: Its working fine in browser and even Android phones having android version 4. But getting this in android 5 and 6

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Simple GET request example:
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'my-url.com/postData',
      data: yourDataObject,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
```

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated.

src : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Tried the solution. but the problem remains same. It works fine in android 4 version. only get data: null in android 5 and 6